# Is Java Cryptography standard libraries in Android run as native code

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, cryptography, standard-library

I am integrating standard java cryptography classes in my Android application, but I noticed that the AES algorithm is not that fast, it cannot encrypt more than about 5 Kb per second, so do someone know if I can get more performance if I implement my own cryptography methods using NDK? or it is just being done already in the standard library? any suggestions is appreciated

Comment: *if I implement my own cryptography methods using NDK* is an absolute no no! The standard cryptography libraries are standards tested and accepted, use them! Unless you are **an expert** on cryptography and **have a Phd in Mathematics**! Instead focus on why you state *the AES algorithm is not that fast*, elaborate on how you come to that conclusion, how did you measure that and come with figure of *about 5 Kb per second*?

Comment: I get the answer thank you, BTW cryptography algorithms does not need PHD in math to be implemented. I am not asking about inventing new algirithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Java Cryptography standard libraries in Android run as native code

On older devices, `javax.crypto` is implemented in Java code. Starting in Android 4.3 or 4.4, Android uses an OpenSSL-based `javax.crypto` provider, so most of the code will be native.

> so do someone know if I can get more performance if I implement my own cryptography methods using NDK?

If by "implement my own cryptography methods", you mean "link to and use `libcrypto`", that may be faster on older devices, but I would not expect much difference on newer devices.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I need